# Hydrogen not running python 3.8

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, atom-editor, hydrogen

For several months I ran anaconda, my default python interpreter, and hence Hydrogen on Python 3.7.6 via Atom. Recently I updated my anaconda to 3.8.2, and immediately, my Hydrogen began showing this error.

Python 3

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main return _run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in from ipykernel import kernelapp as app File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__init__.py", line 2, in from .connect import File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in import jupyter_client File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client__init__.py", line 4, in from .connect import File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 24, in import zmq File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py", line 47, in from zmq import backend File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 40, in reraise(*exc_info) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise raise value File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 27, in _ns = select_backend(first) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend mod = import(name, fromlist=public_api) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py", line 6, in from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py)

When I run python 3.8 code without Hydrogen, it still works, proving the error is Hydrogens

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

outputs: 3.8.2 (default, Mar 25 2020, 08:56:29) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Please don't post the error as a link. Copy paste the error into your question!

Comment: my apologies, this is my first post, so im not too familiar with stackoverflow traditions

Comment: What command(s) did you execute to update Anaconda? Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: conda install https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/3.8.2/download/win-64/python-3.8.2-h5fd99cc_0.tar.bz2

(Dont forget to run anaconda prompt as administrator)